# TensorFlow Keras Sequential API GPU usage

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When using TensorFlow's Keras sequential API is there any way to force my model to be trained on a certain piece of hardware? My understanding is that if there is a GPU to use (and I have tensorflow-gpu installed) I will, by default, do my training on the GPU.

Do I have to switch to a different API to gain more control over where my model is deployed?

Comment: This will help you https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device?version=stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a keras user and I work on ubuntu. I specify a certain GPU as follows:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```

where 0 is the number of GPU. By default, tensorflow uses the first GPU (whose number is 0) if there are several ones on your computer. You can obtain the information of GPUs by typing the following command on your terminal:

```
nvidia-smi
```

or

```
watch -n 1 -d nvidia-smi
```

if you want to refresh your terminal every second. The following picture shows the information of my GPU, and the number of it has been circled by a red box.
[image]